# 'canOpenURL' returning true even when I don't have google maps in my iOS device?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, ios-universal-links

I have GoogleMaps SDK in my app but don't have google maps iOS app in my device but still `UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!)` returns `true` instead of `false`.

How can I handle this problem?

Any Help.

Comment: If you open this link which App is being opened?

Comment: No one. I am receiving call in method `func application(_ app: UIApplication,
                     open url: URL,
                     options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool`

Comment: If your App delegate receives the link comgooglemaps:// this means your App is declaring that it can handle such links. Check custom URL schemes in your App Info.plist/Xcode project settings. You may had accidentally pasted wrong URL scheme there.

Comment: @OleksiyIvanov Thanks. Issue resolved.

Answer (score 3):

yes. it can.

if ANY installed app claims it can handle the url scheme 'comgooglemaps'

there is no 1 to 1 fixed relationship for urls to apps. any app(s) can claim any protocol

---

you cant really avoid this im afraid. not if you use urls. you can look at DocumentControllers or ActivityItems to share with user interaction